# How do I create a function library which I can used across all my Vuejs components?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I currently writing a financial application using Vue.js and Vuetify.  I have a few component files and javascript files like

```
Dashboard.vue
Cashflow.vue
NetWorth.vue
stores.js <- Vue Vuex
```

I have some functions which I need to use across all the Vue.js and javascript files.  Would it be possible for me to perhaps write a function library which can be used across all
the component and js files.

```
function moneyFormat(num)
function IRRCalc(Cashflow)
function TimeValueMoneyCalc(I,N,PV,FV,PMT)
function PerpetualAnnuityCalc(I,PV)
function CarLoanInstallment(V,N)
function HouseLoanInstallment(V,N)
```

I know in C it is very simple just `#include<financial.h>` was wondering is there something similar in javascript.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 3 ways to do this:

1/You can create a helper.js file and import it to .vue files

**// helper.js**

```
export default {
  function moneyFormat(num) { // some logic}
  
}
```

**// Dashboard.vue**

```
<script>
import helper from "helper.js"  //the path may change depends on where you put the js file
methods: {
  useHelper(value) {
    helper.moneyFormat(value)  
  
  }
}
</script>
```

2/Another way is bind the function to Vue prototype
in **main.js**

```
Vue.prototype.$moneyFormat= function moneyFormat(num) {}
```

then in **Dashboard.vue** just call `this.$moneyFormat(num)`. No need to import anything

3/ Use mixins. You can search online on how to use this https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Mixin](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html)

In your `main.js`, add `Vue.mixin`:

```js
import Vue from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";

Vue.mixin({
  methods: {
    helloWorld() {
      alert("Hello world");
    }
  }
});

new Vue({
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount("#app");
```

and then you can call `helloWorld()` method from your component `script` with `this.helloWorld()` or just `helloWorld()` from the template.

You also can use [filters](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/filters.html) if the method is to apply common text formatting

In your `main.js`, add `Vue.filter`:

```js
import Vue from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";

Vue.filter("capitalize", function(value) {
  if (!value) return "";
  value = value.toString();
  return value.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + value.slice(1);
});

new Vue({
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount("#app");
```

and then you can do `{{ "some text" | capitalize }}` to apply `capitalize` filter on `"some text"`

Example here: https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-dirac-esb45?file=/src/main.js:0-226

Answer (score 0):

You can create a single JS file that holds all the helper/util methods, and then export them individually:

```
export function moneyFormat(num) { ... }
export function IRRCalc(Cashflow) { ... }
export function TimeValueMoneyCalc(I,N,PV,FV,PMT) { ... }
export function PerpetualAnnuityCalc(I,PV) { ... }
export function CarLoanInstallment(V,N) { ... }
export function HouseLoanInstallment(V,N) { ... }
```

Then, you can simply import individual methods as of when needed, i.e.:

```
import { CarLoanInstallment, HouseLoanInstallment } from '/path/to/helper/file';
```

This can be quite usefuly for tree-shaking when you're bundling with webpack, for example, so that you don't bundle unnecessary functions that are never used in your project.

Comment: Would it be possible for me to export a class with the functions embedded in the class as methods for functions that are related?  What would be the disadvantage of doing that?

Comment: @Eric You can export a class with static methods, but that doesn’t really have any added benefits on top of the disadvantage of unable to perform tree shaking.